# Is there any REST API to start a SharePoint designer workflow?

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a requirement to start a workflow from outside SharePoint. If any REST API exists to start SharePoint designer workflow.

Can anyone help me with this, which API should I use for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the workflow using JavaScript Client Object Model. To perform this action you need to use SharePoint 2013 Workflow Services JS API.

Detailed explanation of to perform the triggering of workflows with different conditions and parameters is given at [Using SharePoint 2013 Workflow Services JS API](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/607127/using-sharepoint-workflow-services-js-api) and [13: Start Workflow with JavaScript Client Object Model](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-start-workflow-with.html)

Hope this meets your requirement you trying to achieve with Rest API

Answer (score 0):

If are you looking for how to trigger workflow to start from external to sharepoint environment via REST API, I have shared how you could do taht in sharepoint online on office 365 by calling the REST API at _vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery, basically you will need to do HTTP Post at the end point twice, one to get the workflow subscription and the other to trigger the workflow instance to start, find it here https://community.nintex.com/community/tech-blog/blog/2017/01/18/stronger-together-nintex-workflow-cloud-office-365

The same REST end point could be used in sharepoint 2013 as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start workflow using code in client side then it is not possible in REST API but we have JavaScript object model(JSOM).

Can you please check workflow services in JavaScript object model. It is giving method for starting workflow using code.

Answer (score 0):

What about the old http:///_vti_bin/Workflow.asmx
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12/ms492829(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN