# Give the Edit permission only to AssignedTo User on Tasks List

Tags: workflow-tasks-list, item-level-permissions

How Can I assign Edit permission on Tasks list to AssignedTo users only. Any other user can view the Tasks but can not edit/delete the task. Only AssignedTo users can edit that task.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to manually change the permissions of said item, or e.g., implement custom Event Receiver that will modify the permissions when the item is created.

Comment: I have tried to create a workflow to break the permission and assign item level permission for that user. But I am creating a from the workflow, so it does not fire a workflow(on task list) for Item created using a workflow. I am using SharePoint online. So I have to create Remote event receiver and hosted on azure that I don't want to do.

Comment: there is option of firing workflow from client side..try if it helps you.. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203155/is-there-any-rest-api-to-start-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/203163#203163

Answer (score 0):

You can use the designer workflow to user/ group from list and provide item level permission to Only AssignedTo user.

```
Log Remove User from list to the workflow history list

then  Remove these permissions from item in this list

then  Add these permissions to item in this list
```

Add these into **Impersonation Step** available in designer

Comment: I have tried this. But Workflow has not fired for the task which are created by Workflow itself.

Comment: Yes you have to use Impersonate Step in workflow to overcome that problem

Comment: Yes I used that step and workflow on Tasks list has been fired if I created manual task then it works perfectly. But When I created Tasks in Tasks list that time workflow hasn't been fired.